# Unit root near unit circle or near 1?

Tags: time-series, unit-root

According to slide 6 of [Bartlett's Introduction to Time Series Analysis, Lecture 6](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/6.pdf) (with emphasis on slide 6), an autoregressive time series model is stationary if the autoregressive polynomial has a root that is not on the unit circle.  However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_root) defines a unit root as a root having a value 1, which is a lot more specific than being on the unit circle.  Which of the two is a more appropriate definition of a unit root for time series?

P.S.: I'm not sure how much this illuminates the question of whether the theory for unit root applies to roots with a *magnitude* of 1 or roots of *real* value 1.0, but if we adopt the vernacular of signal processing, then roots on the unit circle indicate marginal "stability". Any finite-time input into such a system creates a persistent output (it doesn't die, but neither does it grow geometrically). This is entirely consistent with the non-mean-reverting character of  unit root time series processes. However, the latter seem to focus on step response to an impulse input, whereas marginal stability in general (where roots are not specifically real value 1.0) could yield oscillatory response. Perhaps the reason why they are not given attention in time series is because such behaviour is not typical in models for econometrics, health, and the environment. (Personally, I think it may show up in cyclical predatory/prey relationships).

In any case, I think I should my speculation immediately above as ground truth until I encounter indications to the contrary. This means that all the tests for unit roots, and all the literature on the implications of unit roots for the real world (which I admit to being unfamiliar with at present) focus on roots with real value 1.0. However, this is OK, as these are the only roots of interest for the application areas that time series are used for. This would mean that neither Wikipedia nor Barlett are wrong.

P.P.S. My comment about unit step response to shocks might be overly narrow. It only applies to random walks. Furthermore, my comment about step or oscillatory response is likely too narrow as well. I was leveraging my intuition for second order systems only, but the transfer function for a time series model is in no way restricted to 2nd order systems.  [Cochrane](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/time_series_book.pdf) shows on page 113 (Figure 10.2) various other possibilities.  In fact, on page 41, in the paragraph just preceding Section 6.2, he says that unit roots (with random walk being a single-order unit root) are just one form of non-stationarity.  It's possible that the other responses in Figure 10.2 are due to roots on the unit circle at locations other than 1.0.

For the grey beards: Should this be the answer?  I'm putting this out there because I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 4):

Unit root in time series refers to the complex unit root on the unit circle. However in practice, or dealing with observable time series, the proceses with complex unit roots are rarely observed, whereas the unit root 1 is observed a lot. For unit root 1 implies that that the first difference of the series is stationary. First difference of a log series is simply a growth, and in economics there are lots of series with stationary growth. The most prominent example is the GDP.

The unit root processes arise a special case of ARMA processes. The ARMA process is a stationary process (covariance stationary) which satisfies the equation:

$$\phi(L)X_t= \theta(L)Z_t,$$

where $Z_t$ is a white noise process, $\phi(L)$ and $\theta(L)$ are polynomial lag operators, i.e. polynomials where $\sum_{i=0}^p\phi_iL^i$ and $\sum_{i=0}\theta_iL^i$, where $\phi_i$ and $\theta_i$ are real numbers and $L$ is the lag operator $LX_t=X_{t-1}$ (Sometimes it is called backwards operator and letter $B$ is used).

The polynomials have real coefficients, since the observable series $X_t$ are real. However for finding the conditions when the stationary process exists complex analysis is used. Wold theorem says that every covariance stationary process is actually a linear process which can be expressed as a following series:

$$X_t=\sum_{j}\psi_jZ_{t-j},$$

where $Z_t$ is a white noise process and $\sum_j|\psi_j|<\infty$. Note that this expression can be rewritten as $\sum_j\psi_jL^j$, i.e. as Laurent series. It is then natural to seek such solution for ARMA process, where we can write

$$X_t=\frac{\theta(L)}{\phi(L)}Z_t=\psi(L)Z_t,$$

with $\psi(L)=\sum_j\psi_jL^j$. To make this operational we need to make sure that $\psi(L)$ is well defined and that $\sum_j|\psi_j|<\infty$. For that we use complex analysis which says that analytic function can be expressed as a Laurent series. Since we need $\sum_j|\psi_j|<\infty$, we need that $\psi(z)$ is analytic on unit circle. Since we define $\psi(z)$ as a fraction of two analytic functions, we need that denominator is not zero on the unit circle.

And so we come to unit root process. If $\phi(z)$ has a unit root, then it can be written as either $(1-z)\phi_1(z)$, $(1+z)\phi_1(z)$ or $(1-2zcos\theta+z^2)\phi_1(z)$, where $\phi_1(z)$ is a polynomial without the unit root. The last case for the complex unit root case, where only conjugate unit roots can exist, since the coefficients of polynomial are real.

In all of these cases $\tilde Z_{t}=\frac{\theta(L)}{\phi_1(L)}Z_t$ is a stationary process we can simplify ARMA equation to the following three cases:

1. $X_t = X_{t-1}+ \tilde Z_t$, which corresponds to root 1,
2. $X_t = -X_{t-1}+ \tilde Z_{t}$, which corresponds to the root -1,
3. $X_t = 2\cos\theta X_{t-1}-X_{t-2}+\tilde Z_t$, which corresponds to conjugate complex unit root $\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$.

Looking at possible cases of unit root processes it is clear why the root 1 is preferred.

Below are the examples of such processes, where $\tilde Z_t$ is the a sample of one thousand independent standard normal variables. (The code is in the title of y-axis).

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note**. I took some liberties with mathematics, but the general idea can be presented rigorously. The best example is the [Time series](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~spreij/onderwijs/master/aadtimeseries2010.pdf) lecture notes by A. van der Vaart.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert in the notion of stability but I think Bartlett means all roots outside the unit circle and wikipedia is just incorrectly stated.

Note though that you need to be careful how you define the polynomial. Take for example, the AR(2). $ y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \phi_2 y_{t-2} + e_t $.

Then the AR(2) polynomial can be defined as $ (\lambda^2 - \phi_1 \lambda - \phi_2) $ or as $ (1 - \phi_1 z - \phi_2 z^2)$.

These two polynomials have roots that are reriprocals of each other. In the first case, the AR(2) is stable if the roots are inside the unit circle. In the second case, the AR(2) is stable if the roots are outside the unit circle. So be careful how you define the polynomial before deciding on the statement. For me. its more natural to define it with the z's.

All of this is in Hamilton's text which I highly recommend.

Comment: My version of Hamilton's text (1994) is consistent with Wikipedia.

Comment: @whuber: It's an amazing book and full of various info in different chapters. Chapter 1 is consistent with what I wrote in my answer. But maybe there's a different chapter that talks about it in a different way and more along the lines of wikipedia.

Comment: Good point.  I looked up "Unit Root" in the index, which refers to chapter 15, *Models of Nonstationary Time Series.*  The book has many merits, but providing clear definitions is not one of them.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for explaining where you saw that. I don't have the book in front of me and won't till Tuesday but I'll check it out and let you know what I think. It's not an easy book by any stretch but I'd say its my favorite  and I have many, many time series books.

Comment: @whuber: Agreed that clarity is needed in the form of the polynomial. Being an electrical engineer by training, I'm use to z-transforms. In contrast, time series is often used for econometrics (and environmental/health sciences), where the backshift operator B (or L in some texts) is the inverse of Z. I just clarified my post by highlighting slide 6 in Bartlett's lecture, which adopts the convention $\phi(z)=1-\phi_1z-\ldots-\phi_pz^p$. I find this to be consistent throughout the many textbooks and lecture material I've perused (not necessarily read in detail or understood!).

Comment: @whuber: On slide 6, Barlett distinguishes between simply avoiding the unit circle versus being outside the circle: Stationarity = Roots not on the unit circle, while causality = roots outside of the unit circle. So a stationary process might not be causal. For such processes the roots of the AR polynomial are inside the unit circle. I have to remind myself that this means: (i) the statistical parameters of the noise source do not have a time dependence, and (ii) sample values of the time series are not expressible in terms of past values of the noise source.

Comment: @mlofton: I looked at Hamilton just now (and I might have done so in my surfing before posting). His treatment is consistent the prevailing that a unit root is a root of 1.0 (real number). It is not inconsistent with Barlett's polynomial characteristics of stationarity and causality above.

Comment: @StatSmartWannaB I looked at the chapter that whuber was referring to and that is covering the  non-stationary case where the series is a random walk. But that's not the only way that a series can be non-stationary.  The root of the characteristic equation being on or outside the unit circle ( it depends on which characteristic equation you're referring to ) is the general case . I would read chapters 1 and 2  of Hamilton for the general case. There are a lot of gory details in those chapters but my point is that a random walk-unit root is a specific case of non-stationarity.

Comment: @mlofton: I think we're in agreement there.  I modified the question yesterday to reflect exactly that, though referencing Cochrane's electronic textbook instead of Hamilton.  I also perused Hamilton's Chapter 1 & 2, which is good background.  However, my motivation for posting this question was to determine whether the body of unit root theory, methods, and tests focus only on real roots of value 1.0.  As per the expansion of my question, I strongly suspect that it does.

Comment: @StatSmartWannaB. yes, unit root theory focuses on the value of 1. but note that when you do the augmented dickey fuller test for a unit root, rejection ( of the null that there's a unit root ) is two-sided in the sense that it's a two sided test. So, the unit root is a specific kind of non-stationarity but the region of non-stationarity is larger.  This may actually be why other unit root tests where the null is that there is not a unit root are preferred as the earlier comment noted.  I'm glad were on the same page and good luck.

Comment: my mistake. there wasn't an earlier comment about this. That was a different thread. My point is that the ADF assumes a unit root as the null hypothesis and rejects if the estimate is away from 1.0 in either direction. There are other tests ( that I'm much less familar with ) that assume stationarity ( estimate is less than 1.0 ) for the null. then they only reject the null if there's evidence of a unit root. I'm not clear on how they go about doing this but you may want to check out KPSS and some of the other tests that assume stationarity as the null. The ADF may not really fit your case.

Comment: OK, thanks for carifying.  At this  point, I just wanted to clear up a conceptual confusion on my part as to what the concern about unit roots *really* was -- indeed, what unit roots referred to -- as I read up on "best practice" for model development.  So far, it seems that you should test for unit root to determine whether to difference, but even after you resolve that, you still need stationarity testing. CAVEAT on that last speculation: I'm still have much more reading ahead.

Comment: yes, there'a big controversy in econometrics about trend stationary versus difference stationary so the unit root testing is done often to "prove" difference stationarity.  stationarity testing ( using the ADF ) is also a big deal in cointegration because, if the residuals are stationary after regressing two I(1) series on each other, then this shows that the two series are cointegrated. hamilton's text is really great for all of this. another good text is hayashi's text.. mckinnon and davidson also.  I don't have greene or judge et al but they are supposedly good also. good luck.

Comment: oh, note that the question of "needing to difference" can also be inferred from the acf. if the acf doesn't die down after a reasonable # of lags, this is a strong indication that you need to difference.  using hypothesis testing ( i.e: testing for a unit root ) to determine whether to difference may be a little too "formal" of an approach and could lead to problems.  box and jenkins recommend using the acf. the acf of an I(1) series will be pretty obvious.

Comment: Hi: Note that differencing and looking at acf and pacf is the "box-jenkins" philosophy for how to build  arma models ( which need require stationarity so possibly differencing ). Unit root testing is somewhat more theoretical and used by an econometrician who wants to say A) test for trend stationarity versus difference stationariry or B) test for whether two series are cointegrated.  So, the whole concept of stationarity and how it applies,  really depends on what the particular question-project is. All the best.